# "unhandled checked exception as a thrown exception" in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning chapter 5 of SCJP 6 Study Guide Exam_310-065 and in section *Exception Declaration and the Public Interface* it says

> *"Each method must either handle all checked exceptions by supplying a catch clause or list each unhandled checked exception as a thrown
>   exception."*

How do we list each unhandled checked exception as a thrown exception and how does it look like in the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this:

```
public void foo() throws SomeCheckedException, AnotherCheckedException
{
    // This method would declare it in *its* throws clause
    methodWhichThrowsSomeCheckedException();

    if (someCondition)
    {
        // This time we're throwing the exception directly
        throw new AnotherCheckedException();
    }
}
```

See [section 8.4.6 in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, if you have:

```
public void doSomething() throws SomeException { 
    ... 
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

And you want to invoke `doSomething`, you've got to either `catch` the exception, or declare the method using it as also susceptible of throwing `SomeException`, therefore propagating it further in the call stack:

```
public void doSomethingElse() throws SomeException { 
    doSomething();
}
```

Or

```
public void doSomethingElse() { 
    try { 
        doSomething();
    }
    catch (SomeException) { 
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

Take into account that [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)s are not checked exceptions, so they are an exception to this rule.

Comment: Great! Thank you gentlemen for your explanations.